# What is the best way to pass data from ASP.NET to AngularJS?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, angularjs

I am using ng-grid in an ASP.NET web application to display data from a WCF Service. In this Plunker example the data is stored in a JSON file and then converted by the Angular module.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


$scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){  
    var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
    $scope.myData = pagedData;
    $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};

$scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var data;
        if (searchText) {
            var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
            $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {      
                data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
                    return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                });
                $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
            });            
        } else {
            $http.get('largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad,page,pageSize);
            });
        }
    }, 100);
};

$scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
    enableCellSelection: true,
    enableCellEdit: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    totalServerItems:'totalServerItems',
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
};
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/88x6XI?p=info)

This piece of code was interesting because it read dicrectly from a JSON file  and dynamically bound it to the ng-grid.  I was hoping that I would be able to use the ASP.NET (C#) codebehind to pass a JSON file to the AngularJS code and let it do all of the work to parse it.

**It seems like you cannot do this, so what is the best way to pass data to AngularJS from ASP.NET?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can serialize c# objects into json using ASP.net Web Apis which is probably your best option with angular js. Or you can use ASP.net MVC, though MVC is more of a web framework itself than an API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you're really asking is, how do I pass some server-side information to Javasript? Angular is irrelevant here.

**Solution 1**: just write it to a client-side variable. Something like:

If you're using MVC:

```
var myJson = '@ViewBag.MyJson';
var json = JSON.parse(myJson);
```

If you're using WebForms:

```
var myJson = '<% Response.Write(MyJson); %>';
var json = JSON.parse(myJson);
```

**Solution 2**: define a server-side method that returns your json string, and call it from the client side using Ajax. Then parse it as previously. There's a decent example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_ajax_example.htm).

**Solution 3**: can't you write to your Json file from the server side, before loading it into Angular?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I ended up using the ViewBag to pass my JSON string to a global js variable.  Then accessed it from my angular script file.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Angular directive that handles parsing, and then pass it a JSON file name in your ASP.NET page, like this:

```
// ASP.NET page
<%
    JSONFile.Text = "path/to/json/file.json";
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    // including our parse-json directive as "metadata" in the head
    <parse-json data-json-file="<%JSONFile%>"></parse-json>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

And then your angular directive could look something like this:

```
app.directive('parseJson', ['$http', function ($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      jsonFile: '@'
    }
    link: function (scope) {
      $http.get('my/url/' + scope.jsonFile)
        .success(function (data) {
          // your parsing logic would go here.
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

The `data` prefix on the `data-json-file` attribute is the HTML5 standard for [custom data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

So, to summarize the code above. In our ASP.NET page we are including a custom tag (our angular directive) named `<parse-json>` in the `<head>` of our html page (it doesn't have to be there, but it is sorta metadata so I figured it fit). We are setting the attribute `data-json-file` to equal the path of the JSON file on our server. When angular loads on the client, it will request this JSON file, and then from there you can do whatever you want with it (in your case, parse it).

Hope this helps!